# Next number in the sequence $7,31,211,2311,...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, puzzle

I am trying hard to figure out next number in $7,31,211,2311,...$

I tried as $31=7*4+3$

$211=31*6+25$

$2311=211*11+10$

I also tried as, sum of the digits of each number is $7,4,4,7$ respectively. So the next number has the sum of the digits $4$.

Comment: Guess-the-next-number questions have no place on this site unless the pattern is very obvious or there is surrounding context.

Comment: Its the series of [Euclid numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid_number) : $$31=2\cdot 3\cdot 5+1$$ $$211=2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7+1$$

Comment: By the way such questions a simple google search gives the game away.Just wrote the series 7,31,211 and lo i got an article on Euclid numbers!

Comment: A more specific tool than Google is [The On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/), and a quick search there obtains this sequence.

Answer (score 3):

$$2*3 +1=7$$
$$2*3*5 +1=31$$
$$2*3*5*7+1=211$$
$$2*3*5*7*11+1=2311$$
$$2*3*5*7*11*13+1=30031$$
Can you identify the pattern?